# How can I find the serial number of my Apple Keyboard USB on a mac programmatically from the terminal?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, command-line, usb, serial-number

I would like to retrieve the Apple USB Keyboard's serial number from a command to use in a script.

What command can I use ?

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why? To my knowledge, there's no way to get the serial number through software, and it might be possible to accomplish whatever you're trying to do in an alternative manner.

Comment: In my company, employees exchange keyboards when they are failures. I would like to receive the serial numbers by a script every day to see which changes keyboards

Comment: Afraid you're probably out of luck then.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can. The information that you *can* get is available via System Profiler: `system_profiler SPUSBDataType`, which on my Macbook returns:

```
    Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad:

      Product ID: 0x0259
      Vendor ID: 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.)
      Version: 2.24
      Speed: Up to 12 Mb/sec
      Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
      Location ID: 0x14400000 / 3
      Current Available (mA): 1000
      Current Required (mA): 40
      Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
      Built-In: Yes
```

Comment: I concur with this.. I know my SN of my keyboard and tried searching for it within System Profiler and it simply wasn't reported anywhere.

Comment: That's very funny... I can find the Serial Number ok my Internal Keyboard of my MacBook... But not for USB Keyboard ...

Comment: SPI:

    Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad:

      Product ID: 0x0290
      Vendor ID: 0x05ac (Apple Inc.)
      Version: 1.71
      Serial Number: DQXXXXXXXXXXX
      Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
      Location ID: 0x01000000